# Error: No Firebase App

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using `firebase.auth().signOut()` to log a user out when clicking a logout button.

I have a media query that displays a separate way to access the logout button for mobile users. So on a larger screen, it's simply a button. On a smaller screen, it is accessed via a hamburger menu. Both execute the same code:

```
function() {
 firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

What is odd, is that when the hamburger menu is not displayed (i.e. the normal logout button is there), I can click it and log out successfully. But, when I re-size the screen smaller to show the hamburger menu, I click the menu button, the new logout button is displayed, I click that, and get the error:

> Uncaught Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp().

I am using Firebase globally and not on a 'require' basis. What could be the reason behind this strange behavior?

update: I think it has something to do with the fact that the hamburger menu is hidden until hitting a breakpoint. The menu is not actually added to the DOM until it is visible, and so perhaps it does not have access to the global Firebase app.

Comment: Have you initialised your firebase config?

Comment: @Win yes, it is initialized prior to the app UI ever displaying, which is why I think the problem is related to the hamburger menu component starting out as hidden.